# Passing Unicode strings to printf via ctypes

Tags: python, c, unicode, utf-8, ctypes

I'm testing out the built-in ctypes module for Python 3.x before devoting some time to make a wrapper for my existing C library.

I know that the stdlib functions in C will want ASCII input for anything labeled `char *` in the manual. However, my library is UTF-8 compliant, and I have tested it in C programs. I have also tested that the following code when compiling for C11 is valid and works as expected:

```
printf("Hello, %s!\n", u8"world");
```

However, if I try the same in Python, only the first character in my string is printed.

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

libc.printf(b"Hello, %s!\n", "world") # will print: Hello, w!
```

The Python 3 manual about Unicode implies that Python 3 uses UTF-8 as its character encoding which should avoid embedded `NUL` bytes that `printf` would see and stop reading. If I change the `%s` in my Python test to `%ls`, it prints as expected.

Is Python actually using UTF-16?

Comment: your test with `u8` is not very convincing, `u8` are `char*`, too, and you have only ascii in your string ... Also to switch to utf8 output in a C program, you'd have to switch from the C locale (which is there at startup) to a proper locale.

Comment: Convincing it may not be, but it is UTF-8 and does print correctly, where Python clearly does not work the same; it seems to have embedded `NUL`s. You can try the `printf` test with characters that are not ASCII-compatible as well. `printf` only requires the format string to be ASCII-encoded. The other strings brought in from `%s` formatting can be UTF-8 since while parsing it, the function will not encounter a premature `NUL`.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 (before 3.3) is using either UCS-16 or UCS-32 internally, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode):

> Strings are stored internally as sequences of codepoints (to be precise as Py_UNICODE arrays). Depending on the way Python is compiled (either via --without-wide-unicode or --with-wide-unicode, with the former being the default) Py_UNICODE is either a 16-bit or 32-bit data type.

> #### Py_UNICODE
>
> This type represents the storage type which is used by Python internally as basis for holding Unicode ordinals. Python’s default builds use a 16-bit type for Py_UNICODE and store Unicode values internally as UCS2. It is also possible to build a UCS4 version of Python (most recent Linux distributions come with UCS4 builds of Python). These builds then use a 32-bit type for Py_UNICODE and store Unicode data internally as UCS4.

Comment: Aha. It appears that the Unicode HOWTO document was a bit misleading. It talks about how having embedded `NUL`s is straightforward but problematic and then praises UTF-8 to explain the decision that Python source code would be in UTF-8. What wasn't made obvious in that document was the fact that while the source code is read as UTF-8, the string literals represent UTF-16 characters. One can negotiate this using `str.encode()` as in `"my string".encode("utf-8")` to represent a UTF-8 string.

Comment: This isn't correct Since Python 3.3.  See [Flexible String Representation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393-flexible-string-representation).

Answer (score 1):

What is happening with this line:

```
libc.printf(b"Hello, %s!\n", "world") # will print: Hello, w!
```

is that `ctypes` is marshaling byte strings as `char*` and Unicode strings as `wchar_t*` (UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on OS).  It doesn't really matter what Python is using internally.  I'm on Windows, so I'll use `cdll.msvcrt`, but note that `%s` expects `char*` and `%ls` expects `wchar_t*` for `printf`:

```
from ctypes import *
cdll.msvcrt.printf(b'Hello, %s!\n', b'world') # byte string
cdll.msvcrt.printf(b'Hello, %ls!\n', 'world')  # Unicode string (UTF-16 or UTF-32)
cdll.msvcrt.printf(b'Hello, %s!\n', 'world')   # incorrect!
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, w!
```

Simply use a byte string for `%s` in your example:

```
libc.printf(b"Hello, %s!\n", b"world")
```

You can do your own explicit encoding if you want UTF-8:

```
#coding:utf8
from ctypes import *
cdll.msvcrt.printf(b'Hello, %s!\n', 'αßΓπΣσµτΦ'.encode('utf8'))
```

Output (after changing the Windows console via `chcp 65001`, the UTF-8 code page):

```
Hello, αßΓπΣσµτΦ!
```

Comment: "at least on windows" is more like "only on windows using the microsoft CRT", at least for the wide pendant and upper-case format.

Comment: The point still is, use the correct format code and the correct Python type.  `libc.printf('Hello, %s!\n',b'world')` will print correctly.